# CakePHP 3: How to receive translated content?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to receive a single post translation content to fill form.

**in controller**

```
public function translate($id = null)
    {
        $this->Apartments->locale('deu');
        $apartment = $this->Apartments->get($id);
        .....
        $this->set(compact('apartment'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['apartment']);
    }
```

I haven't received the content translated!

**in table**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('apartments');
        $this->displayField('name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->addBehavior('Translate', ['fields' => ['description']]);
    }
```

What is the correct way to receive a translated content and what do I need to put in Table and Entity Classes to make it work?

**UPDATE** SQL query

```
SELECT Apartments.id AS `Apartments__id`,
       Apartments.user_id AS `Apartments__user_id`,
       Apartments.name AS `Apartments__name`,
       Apartments.slug AS `Apartments__slug`,
       Apartments.description AS `Apartments__description`,
       Apartments.number_of_rooms AS `Apartments__number_of_rooms`,
       Apartments.number_of_beds AS `Apartments__number_of_beds`,
       Apartments.badroom AS `Apartments__badroom`,
       Apartments.surface AS `Apartments__surface`,
       Apartments.internet AS `Apartments__internet`,
       Apartments.air_condition AS `Apartments__air_condition`,
       Apartments.parking AS `Apartments__parking`,
       Apartments.pets AS `Apartments__pets`,
       Apartments.created AS `Apartments__created`,
       Apartments.modified AS `Apartments__modified`,
       Apartments.active AS `Apartments__active`,
       Apartments_description_translation.id AS `Apartments_description_translation__id`,
       Apartments_description_translation.locale AS `Apartments_description_translation__locale`,
       Apartments_description_translation.model AS `Apartments_description_translation__model`,
       Apartments_description_translation.foreign_key AS `Apartments_description_translation__foreign_key`,
       Apartments_description_translation.field AS `Apartments_description_translation__field`,
       Apartments_description_translation.content AS `Apartments_description_translation__content`
FROM apartments Apartments
LEFT JOIN i18n Apartments_description_translation ON (Apartments_description_translation.model = 'Apartments'
                                                      AND Apartments_description_translation.field = 'description'
                                                      AND Apartments_description_translation.locale = 'deu'
                                                      AND Apartments.id = (Apartments_description_translation.foreign_key))
WHERE Apartments.id = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Okay, I found what the problem is, I use an existing database with the data entered by CakePHP 2 based applications. In the i18n the names of the model are written  in the singular, while CakePHP 3 saves in the plural. So in the i18n table I have a model name Apartment, but cakephp3 search Apartments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In comments you mention:

> I use an existing database with the data entered by CakePHP 2 based applications. ... in the i18n table I have a model name Apartment, but cakephp3 search Apartments.

The model field value is the name of the model in CakePHP 2 (which is singular), and the name of the table in CakePHP 3 (which is plural).

To solve the problem, you'd either:

### Migrate the data in the translation tables

This is the most logical solution unless there is still CakePHP 2.x code looking at the translation records, simply update the translation records:

```
UPDATE i18n set model = "Apartments" where model = "Apartment";
... etc ...
```

### Change the reference used

The model field *by default* is the name of the table class, but it doesn't have to be it's [configurable](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.0/src/ORM/Behavior/TranslateBehavior.php#L94):

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    ...
    $this->addBehavior('Translate', [
        'fields' => ['description'],
        'referenceName' => 'Apartment' # <- 
    ]);
}
```

In this way the CakePHP 3.x code will act the same/be compatible with earlier versions.